# How to optimize color ramp for terrain

Tags: web-mapping, tiles, mapnik, color, terrain

I'm working on a project to highlight LiDAR terrain on the web and part of the idea is to show the detail of the data at large scales. I've already read through the excellent [Mapbox guide](https://www.mapbox.com/tilemill/docs/guides/terrain-data/) and I've got the process of mixing color shading, hill shading and slope shading together down.

The problem is the certain areas of our county have vastly different terrain and the color ramp that works for the county as a whole doesn't work very well when zoomed in.

For example here is the county as a whole:
[image: Whole of Lake County, IL]

Zooming into the red box which is part of the Illinois Beach State Park, you can see how little detail is shown:
[image: IL Beach State Park global stretch]

But if we tweak the ramp for this particular area you can see a great amount of detail:
[image: IL Beach State Park global stretch]

I already have a Flask backend using mapnik to dynamically stretch the color ramp for a given area and return it to the client but it seems like I should be able to do some sort of localized stretch and generate static tiles which would be much easier to maintain.

I've tried a few things but I keep coming up with hotspots or blown out areas, does anybody have experience or maybe some ideas I could try?